# Add multiple headers to java http request

Tags: java, http

I would like to add multiple headers to a java HTTP request, I think this is possible using the headers() method in the httpRequest builder, but I can't seem to figure out how:

```
 HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .POST()
            .headers(/*add mutple headers here*/)
            .uri(getUrl())
            .build();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding map of httpheaders to builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64726722/adding-map-of-httpheaders-to-builder)

Comment: You can check this link in StackOverflow for your question
[How to set multiple headers at once in Spring WebClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59133508/how-to-set-multiple-headers-at-once-in-spring-webclient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add multiple headers by invoking `header(String,String)` multiple times...

```
HttpRequest request2 = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
  .header("key1", "value1")
  .header("key2", "value2")
  ... stuff ...
  .build();
```

.. or you may use the varargs `headers(String...)` methods

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
  .headers("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2")
  ... stuff ...
  .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `headers` allow you to pass a single key/value or a list of key/value https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.Builder.html#headers(java.lang.String...).

```java
 HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .POST()
            .headers("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2", "key3", "value3")
            .uri(getUrl())
            .build();
```